# What word do we use for "the thing that an analogy is analogising"? Specifically in the context of "metaphor" and "analogy"

Tags: single-word-requests, research

When it comes to the concept and context of metaphor and analogy (rather than other comparators or comparisons in general), the device is used to describe something else in different terms. Metaphors etc. are used when there is something to describe that is hard to understand (among other uses).

In hebrew, the word for metaphor/analogy is מָשָׁל, "mashal". Every מָשָׁל has a נִמְשַׁל, a "nimshal", which is the [Niphal stem](https://uhg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/stem_niphal.html) (generally passive/reflexive) form of מָשָׁל

> the original thing that is now being made into a מָשָׁל

What is the word for נִמְשַׁל in english? I am thinking maybe "analogue", but not sure. I've seen it before, so I know it exists, I just can't remember it.

---

Example:

> Computer hardware is like a bit like the human brain. The CPU is like the cortex, RAM is like short term working memory and storage is like long term memories.

`If the brain is the analogy, the CPU is the ____ ?`

EDIT: The word `tenor` has been suggested, however I would like to find another word, to research suitable sense of tenor not given at Webster's Dictionary, that might appear more of a fit in the context of "analogy" and/or "metaphor"

Comment: I'll write you an official answer of [**moral**](https://literarydevices.net/parable/). The moral of the story is *seek and ye shall find*. Oh, wrong Testament.

Comment: @YosefBaskin don't worry, that's based on the right Testament ('if you seek Him He will be found', Chronicles 1:28:9). However, moral only applies to moral parables. I want a more general term

Comment: Could you provide some specific examples of the general use you mean.

Comment: Google Translate offers only the "moral" for *nimshal*. Even more literally, you could go with the **analogized**, the most direct translation.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I can't argue with **analogized**. I would still like to seek more answers. There is a word that is designed for this, I just can't remember it (it wasn't **analogized**)

Comment: The terms 'tenor' and 'vehicle' are often used for the real referent and the comparator. 'John is [like] a tiger': tenor _the person John_ and vehicle _your 'standard' tiger_. After Richards.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I fear you've generalised this a tad too far. I would like to appeal for the question to be re-opened. Thank you.

Comment: You ask about the 'thing described' and the 'purported comparator'. This _defines_ what a metaphor is. 'X is a Y' (in some respects) / 'X is like a Y' (in some respects). The latter is the simile version of the metaphor (still the same metaphor). The answer 'tenor ←~~ vehicle' is given at the thread mentioned. This is terminology used in linguistics; there may well be different terminology in other fields (maths, business, psychology ...).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thank you sir. I've updated the question to make it more unique. I hope that helps and makes sense. If not, perhaps you can assist me? The word I am looking for is not tenor (although of course I do not argue that it is correct in general). I am leaning heavily towards "analogue" but not satisfied with it yet

Comment: I'd suggest 'In the metaphor _John is a tiger / John is like a tiger_', 'John' is often called _the tenor_ and the thing he is compared (in part) to, a typical tiger, is called _the vehicle_. Is there another term for 'tenor' as used here: the person / thing we are illustrating by comparison?' You could add research (perhaps 'suitable sense of _tenor_ not given at Webstar's Dictionary').

Comment: Technical terms for cognitive metaphor theories are still settling down. _Source_ and _target_ are common, but it's not clear which communication metaphor is involved here. Classical asymmetric terms like _metaphrand_ and _metaphier_ are on offer, but I don't know anyone who uses them. I tend to think of metaphor as a mapping of one field into or onto another, depending on how thorough the mapping is.

Comment: @JohnLawler thank you. Is it stupid to say, "what about non-technical words"?

Comment: There are even more of them. Take a look at Lakoff and Johnson's _Metaphors We Live By_ to see.

Answer (score 1):

[The Wikipedia article for analogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analogy) says the following:

> Analogy [...] is a cognitive process of transferring information or meaning from a particular subject (**the analog, or source**) to another (**the target**), or a linguistic expression corresponding to such a process.

In the provided example, the brain is the analog/source and the CPU is the target.

There is also [a section discussing the terminology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analogy#Usage_of_the_terms_%22source%22_and_%22target%22).

Comment: So analog/analogue is incorrect, as that's just another way of saying analogy