# Technical term for parts of a metaphor

Tags: metaphors, figures-of-speech

What's the technical term for the "argument" of a metaphor?  For example:

> The world is a vampire, set to drain

*Bullet with Butterfly Wings*, Smashing Pumpkins (1995).

"Vampire" is the metaphor itself.  What is "world"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the terms for the parts of a comparative?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167575/what-are-the-terms-for-the-parts-of-a-comparative) Or [what word do we use for the thing that an analogy is analogising 
 ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/602944/what-word-do-we-use-for-the-thing-that-an-analogy-is-analogising-specifically)? ('tenor' / 'vehicle').

Comment: The first linked answer does, thanks, but @fev's answer below is more comprehensive.  I'm not sure exactly how duplicates work, so if it's possible to preserve fev's answer, it should be so preserved.

Comment: But the references fev gives are ones questioners should consult first in any case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several pair of terms used by different authors or branches of linguistics.

According to Richards, *the world* is ***the tenor*** of the metaphor. Commenting on Shakespeare's metaphor of the world:

> All the world's a stage,
> And all the men and women merely players. 
>  (*As You Like It*, 2/7)

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphor) explains:

> *The Philosophy of Rhetoric* (1936) by rhetorician I. A. Richards describes a metaphor as having *two parts*: **the tenor** and **the vehicle**. ***The tenor is the subject to which attributes are ascribed***. The vehicle is the object whose attributes are borrowed. In the previous example, "the world" is compared to a stage, describing it with the attributes of "the stage"; ***"the world" is the tenor***, and "a stage" is the vehicle; "men and women" is the secondary tenor, and "players" is the secondary vehicle.

[Thought.co](https://www.thoughtco.com/tenor-metaphors-1692531) gives the exact quote saying:

> The terms ***vehicle*** and ***tenor*** were introduced by British rhetorician Ivor Armstrong Richards in *The Philosophy of Rhetoric* (1936).
>
> > ***[V]ehicle*** and ***tenor*** in cooperation give a meaning of more varied powers than can be ascribed to either.

So, in your example, *the world* is ***the tenor***, while *vampire* is ***the vehicle***.

The Wikipedia article also mentions other pairs of terms used to name the two parts of the metaphor. For example:

> Other writers employ the general terms ***'ground' and 'figure'*** to denote the tenor and the vehicle. Cognitive linguistics uses the terms ***'target' and 'source'***, respectively.